# I want to count the number of occurence of a string in a row (specific to 3 columns: B, J, K).

Tags: vba, excel

If the string is present in all 3 columns then the count should be 1 and should start looking for the string in the next row.

Private Sub Button()

```
inputData = Application.InputBox("Enter Application Name:", "Input Box Text", Type:=2)
```

I want a button to get the input string which I use for searching

```
Dim MyCount As Long
MyCount = 0
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = ActiveCell
```

I guess I have some error in the active cell. I guess it should be cell or something of that sort
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Set ws = Worksheets("extract")
    With ws

```
i = 2
MyCount = 0
```

Here goes the loop

```
Do While i < 15506
c = 2
rng = Cells(i, c)
If Not InStr(rng, inputString) = True Then
    c = 10
    rng = Cells(i, c)
    If Not InStr(rng, inputString) = True Then
        c = 11
        rng = Cells(i, c)
        If Not InStr(rng, inputString) = True Then
            i = i + 1
        Else
            MyCount = MyCount + 1
            i = i + 1
            End If
    Else
        MyCount = MyCount + 1
        i = i + 1
        End If
Else
    MyCount = MyCount + 1
    i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
```

for displaying the number of rows

```
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox inputData & "has matched and total count is:" & MyCount
Else
    MsgBox inputData & " not found"
End If
```

End Sub

the total number of rows is: 15505. I'm very new to VB. please let me know if there are any new functions for this.

Comment: There's a simple formula to do this wtihout any vba: `=COUNTIF(1:1,"*CODE*")` where CODE is the word you want to look for and 1:1 is the row you want to look.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I would be more happy if you can elaborate a little more and explain

Comment: also to add on.. I want to search for a total of 15505 rows. how do I count without the loop

Comment: You have `rng` declared as a `Range` variable, but you are trying to use it to store a `String` variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I've understood correctly, but I think this may be what you are looking for:

```
Sub SO()
Dim cCount As Long, i As Long, inputString As String

inputString = InputBox("Enter Application Name:", "Input Box Text")

cCount = 0

  For i = 2 To 15505
     If InStr(Cells(i, 2).Value, inputString) > 0 And _
        InStr(Cells(i, 10).Value, inputString) > 0 And _
        InStr(Cells(i, 11).Value, inputString) > 0 Then cCount = cCount + 1
  Next i

MsgBox "Number of matches is: " & cCount

End Sub
```